Relationship related to sum of squared deviations
I'm trying to prove this equality, in the context of linear regression:
$$
\frac{\sum x_i^2}{n S_{xx}} = \frac{1}{n} + \frac{\bar{x}^2}{S_{xx}}
$$
where
$$
S_{xx} = \sum (x_i - \bar{x})^2
$$
My derivations have led me to:
LHS:
$$
\frac{\sum x_i^2}{n \sum x_i^2 - n^2 \bar{x}^2}
$$
RHS:
$$
\frac{1}{n} + \frac{\bar{x}^2}{\sum x_i^2 - n\bar{x}^2}
$$
Making the denominators common, we are led to their equality.
However, I feel there may be a simpler solution and derivation, or a possible well-known relationship that can be leveraged to derive this. Could anyone enlighten me?

Multiply bith sides with $S_{xx}$. Now you are left with proving the expression $$\frac{1}{n}\sum x_i^2 = \frac{1}{n} S_{xx} + \bar{x}^2$$
or
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum x_i^2  = \frac{1}{n}\sum (x_i - \bar{x})^2 + \left(\frac{1}{n} \sum x_i\right)^2$$
It relates to the relationship between raw moments and centered moments. And it relates to the separation of errors into variance and bias. There are many derivations around.
